# Does internet explorer running in protected mode allows full read access to the user's "My Documents" folder?

Tags: internet-explorer, file-io, add-on, protected-mode

I'm currently developing an IE add-on that needs to read some existing files under the "My Documents" from the current user's profile.

If IE is running in protected mode:

- what care should be taken to always be able to read those files?
- does the virtualization mechanism affects file reads besides writes?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx).  When running in Protected Mode, IE is running as a low integrity process.  Low integrity processes can only write to low integrity write locations.  I think you should be able to read from My Documents, as long as the user has normal permissions to read from there.

Just go ahead and write the code and try it.  If you encounter specific problems I would come back and ask those as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! It should me mentioned that, if a write to a file (in protected mode) under MyDocuments is made, that files gets virtualized in a safe folder: under Temporary Internet Files\LocalLow. Then, following reads to that file will access the one in that directory intead of the one in MyDocuments

Comment: P.S.: look at the article Jeff posted, it's a great resource to learn about IE Protected Mode.